# Default/logical directory structure for Django

Tags: django, python-3.x, heroku

I have gone through a number of tutorials, built a few apps, and even read the book by one of the creators of Django.  But I am mystified by the 'proper' directory structure.

One always seems to get a tree that looks like this (with a virtual environment at the top):

```
venvdir
   |
   +---manage.py 
   |
   +---mysitedir 
   |       +--settings.py
   |       +--urls.p
   |       +--staticfiles (where collectstatic puts everything)
   |
   +---myapp1dir
   |       +--views.py
   |       +--models.py
   |       +--staticdir
   |             +---static-objects-tree...
```

What I find confusing is that

```
 os.path.abspath(__file__)
```

points to 'mysitedir' (the references say it always points to the dir with settings.py in it).

Presumably the idea is that a whole 'site' has one or more 'apps' under it, though I have never seen that done as such.

First, is that correct?

Second, is there some compelling reason (or am I doing it wrong) such that the 'apps' don't slot in below 'mysitedir'?  That would seem to make more sense and maintain modularity.

It seems odd the way Django does things like going through the whole tree looking for static files.  It also seems illogical that you list the 'apps' in settings.py, and - once again - Django needs to go traversing up and back down to find these files (instead of just being able to look in the directory specified by os.path.abspath(**file**).

Comment: Where you put the venv in some ways depends more on your devops and where you intend to build.  If you build in AWS via elasticbeanstalk i'll normally put it up in the parent locally just so I don't need to .gitignore it.  If you use docker to deploy you might place differently.  Don't go overboard with apps and models.  Thats historically made migrations gnarlier.  https://medium.com/cs-math/11-things-i-wish-i-knew-about-django-development-before-i-started-my-company-f29f6080c131

Comment: Having used Django since 1.3, they keep changing the directory structure (or they did). Hopefully they have decided that this one is not going to change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the default project layout is just a suggestion, there's nothing stopping you putting your apps in the `mysitedir` if you wish.

Django wants it to be easy to make re-usable apps. When you run `manage.py runserver`, the directory containing `manage.py` is on the Python path. Therefore you can import apps in that directory with `myapp1`, `myapp2` etc.

If you moved the apps to the inner `mysitedir` (the one that contains settings), then you would import the apps with `mysitedir.myapp1`, `mysitedir.myapp2` etc. Your code now has the project name hardcoded, so it is less reusable.

Finally, Django doesn't really go "traversing up and down" the directories of the project. When you do `import myapp`, Python imports the module from the Python path. This could be the outer project directory that contains `manage.py`, or if it's an installed package, it could be somewhere completely different.

Comment: Got it - great explanation.  Django is clever, but sometimes cryptic.